# Change an href tag on a button based on which option is selected

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to update the link on the button at the end of the page based on which option is selected in the dropdown, but it's not updating.

I tried making a function in JavaScript to change the link, then call on that function whenever an option is clicked. But the link remains the same.

I'm using bootstrap if that matters.

```js
function changeLink(unit_link) {
      document.getElementById("forecast_button").href = unit_link;
      alert(getElementById("forecast_button").href)
    }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>Tactical Volume Forecaster</h1>
  <p>Which unit are you forecasting for?</p>
  <select class="form-select" aria-label="Default select example" id="unit">
    <option selected>...</option>
    <option value="Sales" onclick="changeLink('/volume_forecaster/result/Sales');">Sales</option>
    <option value="Client_Service" onclick="changeLink('/volume_forecaster/result/Client_Service');">Client Service</option>
    <option value="Agency" onclick="changeLink('/volume_forecaster/result/Agency');">Agency</option>
    <option value="Experts" onclick="changeLink('/volume_forecaster/result/Experts');">Experts</option>
  </select><br/><br/>

  <a href="/volume_forecaster/" class="btn btn-info" role="button" id="forecast_button">Get Forecast</a>

</div>
```

Comment: "link on the button" `<button>`  tags do not have href, anchor tags `<a>` do try to be precise in your description.

Comment: Sorry, I'm very new to this and don't know all the right terminology.

Comment: No need for apology; we all started somewhere - very often there is already an existing similar question on something that creative searching can find.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should listen for the `onchange` event on the `<select>` tag.

```js
  function changeLink() {
    var selectedUnit = document.getElementById("unit").value;
    var unitLink = "/volume_forecaster/result/" + selectedUnit;
    document.getElementById("forecast_button").href = unitLink;
  }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>Tactical Volume Forecaster</h1>
  <p>Which unit are you forecasting for?</p>
  <select class="form-select" aria-label="Default select example" id="unit" onchange="changeLink()">
    <option selected>...</option>
    <option value="Sales">Sales</option>
    <option value="Client_Service">Client Service</option>
    <option value="Agency">Agency</option>
    <option value="Experts">Experts</option>
  </select><br/><br/>

  <a href="/volume_forecaster/" class="btn btn-info" role="button" id="forecast_button">Get Forecast</a>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For selects, your best option is detecting change not click.

Here I have the href as a data attribute on each option and just use an event handler to detect the change.

```js
let unit = document.querySelector("#unit");
let btn = document.querySelector("#forecast_button");
unit.addEventListener("change",() => {
    btn.href = unit.querySelector("option:checked").dataset.href;
    console.log(btn.href)
});
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>Tactical Volume Forecaster</h1>
  <p>Which unit are you forecasting for?</p>
  <select class="form-select" aria-label="Default select example" id="unit">
    <option selected>...</option>
    <option value="Sales" data-href='/volume_forecaster/result/Sales'>Sales</option>
    <option value="Client_Service" data-href='/volume_forecaster/result/Client_Service'>Client Service</option>
    <option value="Agency" data-href='/volume_forecaster/result/Agency'>Agency</option>
    <option value="Experts" data-href='/volume_forecaster/result/Experts'>Experts</option>
  </select><br/><br/>

  <a href="/volume_forecaster/" class="btn btn-info" role="button" id="forecast_button">Get Forecast</a>

</div>
```